# scroll in both directions with iScroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, iscroll4

I would like to make an image slide with momentum freely in any direction (no snap).

I came across [iScroll4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4), which is a great script (works great on iOS and Android).

JS CODE:

```
var myScroll;
function loaded() {

myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', 
                { hScrollbar: false, 
                    vScrollbar: false,
                    snap:false,
                    vScroll: true,
                    hScroll: true
                     });
}
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="scroller">
        <div id="thelist">
            <img id="theImg" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width="300px" height="200px">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body,ul,li {
padding:0;
margin:0;
border:0;
}


#wrapper {
position:absolute; 
z-index:1;
top:-500px; 
bottom:0px; 
left:-500px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow:auto;
background-color: red;
}

#scroller {
position:absolute; 
z-index:1;
padding:0;
width: 2000px;
height: 5000px;
background-color: blue;

}

#thelist {
list-style:none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
text-align:left;
background:none;
background-color: yellow;
}

#theContent {
background-color: grey;
}

#theImg {
position: relative;
top: 500px;
left: 500px;
}
```

I tried to make the wrapper bigger than the screen, so the image can slide outside the screen, and then make the image in a relative position, so it's initially visible on the screen.

But I can't seem to get rid of the top or left snapping.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Alternatively, is there another library that can do the same job ?

Comment: I've used iScroll before and found it a little finnicky. I've had better luck with NiceScroll (requires jQuery): http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/

Comment: Thank's for the reply, unfortunatly I'm using GWT which doesn't apprear to support jQuery..

Comment: To the **#wrapper** in your style give height and width in pixel and check it.